# Retrieving JS Object using Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I'm hoping someone can guide me in the right direction, I'm trying to retrieve an object on a page via Puppeteer.

If I type the following in Web Console, it works:

```
eval('__object.client[0]');
```

This works perfectly fine, if I try to do this in Puppeteer doing:

```
await page.exposeFunction('findPath', (search) => {
    console.log(eval('__object.client[0]'));
});
```

It doesn't retrieve the object but instead just the string.

What have I done wrong?

Thanks all.

Comment: Do you want to expose that function? Wouldn't the `evaluate` function work for you?

Comment: @hardkoded I'm wanting to do other things with it, I tried the evaluate function but didn't do anything :/

Comment: When I do `console.log(await page.evaluate('__object.cfg.client[0]'));`, it says `Error: Evaluation failed: ReferenceError: __object.cfg.client[0] is not defined`

Comment: Well that's a javascript error on the browser side, it just means that some variable there is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are some concepts you have to keep in mind:

`exposeFunction` won't execute that function. It will register that function so you can then call `findPath(foo)` **in the browser context**.
The code you run inside the exposed function **will run in the context of your app**. So the `eval` won't work there.

`evaluate` should do the work for you:

```js
console.log(await page.evaluate(() => {
   return eval('document.title');
}));
```

With `evaluate` you have to keep in mind that the code will be executed in the browser context. So you won't read any console log on the app side (unless you listen to the log event).

Comment: I'm wanting to call findPath(), the idea is I need to retrieve the object first to use inside my function. When trying to use eval to get my object, I get 'undefined' yet it works in the browser. I do listen to log `page.on('console', (msg) => console.log('[WEB-CONSOLE] ' + msg.text()));`

Comment: you can call findPath using an evaluate. `await page.evaluate("findPath('foo')");`

Comment: `Error: Evaluation failed: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON`